# Запрос через suds с пустым аргументом

Tags: python, soap, wsdl

Второй день бьюсь с вроде бы пустяковой задачей, связанной с отправкой soap-запроса через библиотеку suds под питоном.

Нужно отправить запрос с двумя параметрами.

На стороне питона это делается так:

```
client.service.exportSomething(id, tstamp)
```

Если оба параметра присутствуют, то всё работает отлично, генерится и отправляется вот такой xml:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://наш_сервер">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:exportSomething>
         <ns:some_id>xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</ns:some_id>
         <ns:tstamp>2000-01-01 00:00:00</ns:tstamp>
      </ns:exportSomething>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Проблема в том, что оба параметра должны быть опциональными. Я пробовал вместо них ставить пустую строку, `None`, suds.null(). В этом случае библиотека генерит запрос, где теги параметров пустые. Например, если пытаюсь подставить пустое значение вместо tstamp, получается такой xml:

```
...
  <ns:exportSomething>
     <ns:some_id>xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</ns:some_id>
     <ns:tstamp/>
  </ns:exportSomething>
...
```

И вместо ответа я получаю ошибку.

Нагуглил, что нужно в xml запроса прописать в заголовочном теге вот такое: `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` и тогда можно будет указывать отсутствие значения вот так:

```
        <ns:tstamp xsi:nil="true" />
```

Если я отправляю такой xml-запрос вручную (например через программу SoapUI), то я получаю именно такой ответ, которого ожидаю.

Но как мне отправить такой запрос в питоновском скрипте через suds?

UPD: После того, как при создании объекта client я закомментил настройки cache, начали адекватно работать запросы с suds.null() в качестве аргумента. Как это может быть связано, и что мне нужно сделать, чтобы всё работало при включенном cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После чистки кэша всё заработало как надо.

Я так и не понял, почёму при нечищеном кэше suds обрабатывал suds.null() так, будто это обычный None.